# Layout appearance collision

Tags: android, layout, appearance

When i add `GridView` to layout hierarchy he displayed as `ListView`. What the **mistique**?

[image]

And `ListView` :

[image]

UPD:

I guess that's problem in sdk. But i want to see any feedback. Maybe anyone reproduced thats problem like me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `android:numColumns` attribute to something greater than `1`.

Comment: Pff... it's was so easy. Thank's man.... I accept it during 10 minutes. Stack disallow so fast actions:)